# Ordered list with Sandcastle Help File Builder

Tags: sandcastle, shfb

How do I make a list in xmldoc blocks render as an ordered list when I create a chm with Sandcastle Helpfile Builder?

The following does not work:

```
/// <list type="numbered">
///     <item>Built in support for foobar</item>
///     <item>Client gooblygook and associated javascript support</item>
///     <item>Client side ability to read values from control</item>
///     <item>AJAX support via ASP.NET callbacks</item>
///     <item>Smaller HTML and Javascript footprint when compared to the crappy thirdparty control we paid too much for.</item>
/// </list>
```

In the particular case I am trying to solve for, the list is within a <summary/> element.

Comment: Don't know, but Have you tried putting it in <remarks/>?  Maybe lists are not supported in the summary element.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just in case anyone runs across this question - the correct implementation is:

```
    /// <list type="number">
    ///     <item>Built in support for foobar</item>
    ///     <item>Client gooblygook and associated javascript support</item>
    ///     <item>Client side ability to read values from control</item>
    ///     <item>AJAX support via ASP.NET callbacks</item>
    ///     <item>Smaller HTML and Javascript footprint when compared to the crappy thirdparty control we paid too much for.</item>
    /// </list>
```

It does not have to be in the `<remarks>` section.

Read more at [<list> (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y3ww3c7e%28VS.80%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks! I didn't expect this to get an answer.

Comment: Interestingly on the sandcastle page you will find a completely different syntax described. https://ewsoftware.github.io/MAMLGuide/html/d6c82cde-f889-4ac9-b3a7-7d45fd6fbffc.htm

Comment: @AnorZaken interestingly enough that was the documentation that I was looking at as well, but it is definitely out of date. I came across this post because my lists weren't working, but in my case I was using `<list class="bullet">` instead of `<list type="bullet">` as referenced in this documentation: [Sandcastle XML Comments Guide - List](http://ewsoftware.github.io/XMLCommentsGuide/html/e433d846-db15-4ac8-a5f5-f3428609ae6c.htm). Obviously the `class` attribute was changed to `type` at some point.